# make buttons align after a space using the wrap widget

Tags: flutter

the 2 buttons in the image [image]wrap to next line like this [image] I'd like to make the buttons to align under "make buttons wrap... " instead of under the avatar. I've tried  the different properties of `Wrap` but with no success. I'm wondering can I do this with wrap.. Or should I take a different approach .

Comment: You probably should use a column + row widget. 1st column = avatar, 2nd column = row [name , buttons]

Comment: should of pointed out I don't have an option to change the layout

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this layout:
[image]
More robust than using wrap, I think.

Comment: should of pointed out I don't have an option to change the layout